# Auto start Notepad++ macro

Tags: boot, notepad++, macros

Is there a way to auto start a Notepad++ macro? I have a macro created but I want it to be run automatically when Notepad++ starts.

Comment: I know you can have NP++ execute a NPPExec script/command at start up. For that you need to go to `Plugins>NPPExec>Advanced Options>Execute this script when Notepad++ starts`...So all you need is call a macro from NPPExec and this is tricky I guess. See this http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/3774271

Comment: Stat-R's comment should be accepted as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the perfect and efficient solution but if you need something complicated it can be of great help.

I can do that if I use any other script besides NPPExec. This can be done via `Send` command in [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm). @Jerph has suggested AutoHotkey which can also be used. 
So here are the steps:

1. Download [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/)
2. Write a script to send keystrokes through autoit file (SendToNppExec.au3).
3. Write a NPPExec Script to run SendToNppExec.au3 using AutoIt3_x64 (*or whatever windows version you are using*).
4. Enable the script to be executed when NPP starts

Suppose the keyboard shortcut  for your macro is Ctrl + F12.
Then you can write an autoit script (**SendToNppExec.au3**) as follows:

Send ( "^{F12}" )

Then use NPPExec to execute the following command at start up:
You may include the following in your NPPExec Script which you have to choose to start when Np++ starts.

```
"C:\...path to...\AutoIt3_x64.exe" "C:\...path to...\SendToNppExec.au3"
```

I guess you understand the following image to enable NPPExec script on start up.

[image]

**EDIT**
You can also convert the au3 script to exe and then call directly from NPPExec script without having to invoke AutoIt3 application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to look into the exact commands you need, but I wanted to point you to [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which can create inputs when a program starts (and much, much more). I'm not an expert, but to give you a possible direction, I've writen an AHK script that clicks on a certain menu item as soon as a dialog window appears. Just have a look at the documentation for some commands you can use.

Hope that helps!