# Running macro through NPPExec (Notepad++)

Tags: script, notepad++, macros, nppexec

Is there a way to run a **macro** using **NPPExec** script in **notepad++**? Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried to find the solution [here](http://trac.pcbsd.org/browser/pbibuild/modules/notepadpp/overlay-dir/notepadpp/drive_c/Program%20Files/npp.5.3.bin/ansi/plugins/doc/NppExec_Manual.txt?rev=3878) and the NPPExec Manual that can be accessed within NPPExec menu of NP++. I have successfully run many applications (like R, pdflatex etc). But I was unable to run (or even access) macro through NPPExec.

Comment: the above link died

Answer (score 1):

This [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/3774271) link shows something along the lines of what you're looking for. Go through it in detail. I don't have too much experience working with Notepad++ macros, but it seems that you can accomplish only Scintilla hacks this way. None of the methods in the page are **exactly** what you're looking for, but this is closest.

Comment: I want to run any macro (starting with the in build ones). Do you have a way? See my edits @ prrao

Comment: Are you referring to inbuilt Notepad++ Macros? Or external macros like VBAs?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear. I am taking about inbuilt Notepad++ macros

Comment: @Stat-R Are you looking to run a bunch of macros through a script? Can't you just run them one by one using shortcuts? That seems to be your best bet since NppExec doesn't seem to have this functionality

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and could find some level of solution. One can use [Send command](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) in [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/)  to send short-cut keys corresponding to the macro using NPPExec. More complicated tasks can be automated using this strategy. A similar post can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/411018/auto-start-notepadd-macro/415839#415839)